# Are there any possibilities to change the CPTPlotSymbol origin in CorePlot?

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

Is there any possibility to change the origin of predefined "CPTPlotSymbol"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is an outstanding request to add this feature on the [Core Plot issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=430). You can monitor that issue page to find out if and when it gets added.